# How to use do-while loop continuously with a new values for the variables involved (re-input by user)?

Tags: c++

This code solves for the root of a cubic function. Setting aside any mathematical concepts, SPECIFICALLY I want to do my DO-WHILE LOOP THREE TIMES (for it's cubic). Consequently, the user will input a guess of the root, v THREE TIMES.

Now the problem is after the FIRST DO-WHILE LOOP, the values of the variables v, seemed to be NOT OVERWRITTEN by the re-input of the user for the SECOND and THIRD DO-WHILE LOOP.

[image]

Please help guys!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const double R = 0.082054;

double f(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v);        
double f(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v)
{
    double q =P*pow(v,3)-(P*b+R*T)*pow(v,2)+a*v-a*b;
    return q;
}
double fPrime(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v);
double fPrime(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v)
{
    double s =3*P*pow(v,2)-2*(P*b+R*T)*pow(v,1)+a;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    double a,b,P,T,Tc;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> P;
    cin >> T;

    double v,v1=0,fv,fv1,N,e;                                   //FIRST DO-WHILE
    int iteration = 0;
    cout << "\nUse initial guess for molal volume, v: ";
    cin >> v;
    cout << "\nUse maximum number of iterations, N: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "\nUse tolerance, e: ";
    cin >> e;
    do
    {
        v = v1;
        fv = f(a,b,P,T,v);
        fv1 = fPrime(a,b,P,T,v);
        if (fv1==0)
        {
           cout << "Math Error";
           break;
        }
        v1 = v-(fv/fv1);
        cout << iteration+1 << setw(12) << v << setw(16) << v1 << setw(16) << abs(v1-v) << endl;
        iteration++;
    }
    while(iteration<N && abs(v1-v)>e);
    cout << "The approximate root/solution is " << v1 << endl;

    iteration = 0;                                              //SECOND DO-WHILE
    cout << "\nUse initial guess for molal volume, v: ";
    cin >> v;
    cout << "\nUse maximum number of iterations, N: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "\nUse tolerance, e: ";
    cin >> e;
    do
    {
        v = v1;
        fv = f(a,b,P,T,v);
        fv1 = fPrime(a,b,P,T,v);
        if (fv1==0)
        {
           cout << "Math Error";
           break;
        }
        v1 = v-(fv/fv1);
        cout << iteration+1 << setw(12) << v << setw(16) << v1 << setw(16) << abs(v1-v) << endl;
        iteration++;
    }
    while(iteration<N && abs(v1-v)>e);
    cout << "The approximate root/solution is " << v1 << endl;

    iteration = 0;                                              //THIRD DO-WHILE
    cout << "\nUse initial guess for molal volume, v: ";
    cin >> v;
    cout << "\nUse maximum number of iterations, N: ";
    cin >> N;
    cout << "\nUse tolerance, e: ";
    cin >> e;
    do
    {
        v = v1;
        fv = f(a,b,P,T,v);
        fv1 = fPrime(a,b,P,T,v);
        if (fv1==0)
        {
           cout << "Math Error";
           break;
        }
        v1 = v-(fv/fv1);
        cout << iteration+1 << setw(12) << v << setw(16) << v1 << setw(16) << abs(v1-v) << endl;
        iteration++;
    }
    while(iteration<N && abs(v1-v)>e);
    cout << "The approximate root/solution is " << v1 << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know there's an analytic way of solving a cubic?

Comment: Look at the first line of the loop and ponder what it does. (Is there a difference between these loops? If not, why don't you encapsulate it in a function?)

Comment: Yeah sir. It's for numerical methods class, specifically newton's method. I know it's not good for solving polynomials, but I just want to finish what i started hehe. The only thing left is that the variables must be OVERWRITTEN by the next set of inputs by the user for the values of v, N, and e.

Comment: I don't have any ideas aside from this for I am a beginner. Simply put, just like in the SHIFT SOLVE of calculator, say first i set v =0, then it gives me a root. the i try v=10 for the other root, then v = -10 for the last root

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your line 'cin>>v;' is pointless in your code, because every time you are reading v, you immediately afterwards assign the value of v1 to v with 'v=v1' . So your initial guess is lost. 
Moreover, since the exit condition for your second do-while is the same as the exit condition for your first do-while, the second do-while should only execute once and the value of v after that execution should equal v1 = v-fv/fv1, so you will never get a new second value for v distinct from the first value.

Comment: Thanks for commenting sir! I didn't notice that thanks sir. But i don't get your second statement

Comment: All I meant to say with my second comment was that v1 is the same in between your second and first do-while's and therefore, since abs(v1-v)<=e was true after your first do-while, it will stay true after doing v=v1 and v1=v-fv/fv1. So maybe you should reset the value of v1 after your first do-while and not just reset the value of v.

Comment: Oh i see! Thanks sir! My code works now! I am getting the 3 roots now thanks sir! Hehe